# Can't stay logged in on Google Chrome

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu, google-chrome, restart

I'm using Google Chrome 31.0.1650.63 on Ubuntu 13.04 (raring). It was all working fine but since last day whenever I restart my computer, I'm automatically logged off all the sites (such as Stack Exchange sites, Facebook, Google etc.).

I followed the steps given on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/236434/133170) to enable logging on Google Chrome, but I couldn't find anything suspicious in the logs.

I've checked the Content Settings in Google Chrome, and it is set to "*Allow local data to be set (recommended)*".

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so my problem turned out to be that I had a corrupt Cookies file. I manually deleted the `Cookies` file in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/` and that fixed the issue.

For ease of copy/paste, here are the commands:

```
cp ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies.bak
rm ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies
```

As Yalok has said in comments below, if you have multiple profiles, you can do this:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/Profile*/Cookies
```

Comment: This still works in 2018 on Ubuntu 18.04, Chrome 66. 
If you have multiple profiles, you have to delete the Cookies directory for all of them: `rm -rf  ~/.config/google-chrome/Profile*/Cookies`

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, Chrome has a new thing to try: in the pic of you logged in next to the three dots in the upper right corner, click on it. There is a gear next to the "other people" choice. Deleting everyone (I had multiple copies of myself) and start over with the login and sync process. Did the trick for me (lubuntu 20.04 on an "Early 2011 MacBook Pro")