# Ubuntu 18 Disable Auto Login

Tags: auto-login

I enabled Autologin during current installation of Ubuntu 18 Bionic Beaver.

I would like to Disable the AutoLogin but going to:

"Settings -> Details -> Users"

Doesn't give me the ability to turn the autologin off.

My last resort is to redo the installation without enabling it.

Comment: please provide an image of the unlocked admin user on your system of the "users" option in "details".  The "autologin" IS there as a slider.

Comment: Select the account settings from the drop down in your ubuntu desktop and turn on there. From the settings, it is under details->users. You may need to unlock it before you can modify the switch.

Comment: Rinzwind: The "Autologin" slider doesn't work, that's why I said it doesn't give me the ability to turn it off

Comment: I did say "of the unlocked admin user"  ;-)

Comment: You are right! Not used to the new layout of 18.04 and didn't notice the  "unlock" button at that time.  Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out!

At

"Settings -> Details -> Users"

on the top right corner there was a button to "Unlock".

Clicking that, entering my password gave me the permission to use that slider to turn Autlogin off.

Comment: Doesn't work! I've tried that button in both the on and off settings

Answer (score 2):

There are some bugs in configuring with GUI on Ubuntu 18.10. 
But the configuration can be changed by editing `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`, comment out lines related to auto login:

```
[daemon]
#AutomaticLoginEnable=True
#AutomaticLogin=username
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for an answer, then had an epiphany. It's so much different on KDE Plasma instead of gnome. So, thank you for helping me answer my own question, and here's my findings for others - as this is the post that comes up on google for this setting.

For KDE Plasma it's Settings->Startup and Shutdown->Login Screen (SDDM). Click the behavior button, and then uncheck the "Automatically log in:" for the desired user in the dropdown. Hit 'Apply', enter your password in the security dialog and away you go!