# Auto-login problem in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, login, auto-login

To use my fingerprint sensor to login into my pc I tried to install some programs to use it, first I tried this one [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049526/fingerprint-activation-on-ubuntu-18-04), as it didn't work I tried another one which is [here](https://primetechindia.blogspot.com/2017/11/how-to-setup-fingerprint-lock-in-ubuntu.html), after installing this my I couldn't login into my system using my password, it showed something like- "password didn't work". That's why I uninstalled the programs installed from the two links I just linked above and I successfully managed to log in but without password, from then to now I tried many times to turn auto-login off but failed. FYI, I already tried these: [here](https://vitux.com/how-to-enable-disable-automatic-login-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050802/ubuntu-18-disable-auto-login) and also I should mention that when I start my system and tried to run any browser it asks for a password for one time and it works fine there.

Comment: When testing such features, a good idea is to test with a _different account_...  so keep your main account accessible as normal, and test such features with that other account until it works.