# Always logged out from Chrome

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, browser

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Chrome 53.0.2785.101, and am experiencing the problem,that whenever I boot my laptop and open up Chrome, I'm logged out. I see a yellow triangle next to my name and have to reenter my password. This happens every time, and I don't know why. I don't delete my cookies etc. after I close chrome, but have to log into every website again (Facebook is pretty annoying because of 2FA).

Things I considered why this could happen:

- I recently changed my password.
- I'm using a WiFi connection (Can't use wired atm)

How do I find out what's the problem here and why this is happening? On my desktop pc I don't have the problem.

**Update**
This is not a duplicate of [After rebooting I need to log in each time in Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822804/after-rebooting-i-need-to-log-in-each-time) because the accepted answer didn't work. Maybe I should try one of the others in that thread?

**Update 2**
After the weekend, I had the same problem again. :( Online account is still connected though, but I was still logged out from every site and my Google account.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did what the accepted answer suggested. Will reboot now and see if it works :)

Comment: Sorry @edwinksl but it didn't work. Had the same issue. Logged out of all services and had to re enter my password.

Comment: Ah okay, I will remove the dupe then. Hopefully there is a solution soon!

Comment: Can't believe it. A non-accepted, non-voted answer of the thread worked! I just rebooted and am logged in. I added my google account to the online accounts of ubuntu! But I will test tomorrow again to be 100% sure that it works.

Comment: Heh, awesome. If it does indeed work, please do consider marking this question as duplicate. :)

Comment: I'll wait till tomorrow, and if the problem still does not occur I will mark it. :)

Comment: Looks like the answers in the duplicate target didn't work for you. I am going to vote to reopen this question.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issue after switching from Gnome3 to KDE5 (Ubuntu 18.04).
This answer has helped me: https://askubuntu.com/a/401996/432944

Comment: Can confirm, had the same problem. Deleting chrome cookies file in ~/.config/google-chrome/Default

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. It has something to do with cookies. An option in the cookie settings is probably turned on; it is called "Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows".

If this option is on every time  you close Chrome it will automatically clear the cookies which causes your accounts to log out.

To fix this go to:

**Settings > Privacy and Security > Cookies and other site data > Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows** and turn that setting off.