# Virtualbox Ubuntu log out when open google chrome

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, google-chrome

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on virtual box 6.1.14.

Whenever I open google chrome, I am automatically logged out of Ubuntu system and asked for log in again.
I've tried the solution here [Always logged out from Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823874/always-logged-out-from-chrome), but did not work for me.

**Updates:**
When I type 'google-chrome' in terminal, it gave me the following message:

```
zw@zw-VirtualBox:~$ google-chrome-stable

[9762:9762:0910/103601.639760:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

Comment: Can you run `google-chrome-stable` from the terminal and post the results? Add to your question, please.

Comment: @ajgringo619, I've posted the results from terminal.