# Google Chrome for Linux keeps requesting me to login

Tags: 16.04, login, google-chrome

Brand new to the world of Linux, slowly learning as I go.

I installed Chrome with the following code:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

It seemed to work fine but every time I close the browser it forgets my login.

I use the same settings as I do on Windows and it works just fine there.

All settings are default and I am using a two factor authentication on my account.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it's a brand new install. 
Chrome version is Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit)

Funny thing is, if I try to use an app password in my account it still doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After rebooting I need to log in each time](http://askubuntu.com/questions/822804/after-rebooting-i-need-to-log-in-each-time)

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://askubuntu.com/a/401996/432944